# A cell for a row in collection cell swift?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, cell, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collection view . I want to make each cell take a row programatically . Here is what I've done so far :

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.challenges.count
    }

    // make a cell for each cell index path
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        // get a reference to our storyboard cell
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell


        cell.myLabel.text = self.challenges[indexPath.item]
        cell.backgroundColor = .orange

        return cell
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")
    }

}



class MyCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!

}
```

Any idea what to do next ?
 [image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want each cell to take up the whole width of the view:

The easiest way to do this, since you already set the delegate of the collectionView to the parentViewController, is to implement the following function: `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize` and make it return a size with `self.view.bound.width` as width.

This function is part of the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`, and the only requirement to make it work is the class implementing said function is the collectionView's delegate.

Comment: I am unable to find the function you've mentioned . I tried to write it as follow : but I wont get called at all :
 
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize{
        
        let size = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width , height: 10)
        
        return size ;
    
    }

Comment: Is the viewcontroller containing said function implementing the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` protocol? And if so, did you set it as the delegate for the collectionView?